# Interview - find all pairs of array elements whose sum is known

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I was asked this question:
given an array of size `n` of `int`s and `int sum`, I need to return all pairs of the array's elements whose sum is equal to `sum`

```
std::vector< std::pair<int,int> > find(int* arr,size_t n,int sum)
```

The arrays is not sorted.
I have proposed an O(n) time solution using a hash table:

```
traverse the arr 
  if arr[i] is in the hash 
       vector.push_back (make_pair(arr[i],sum-arr[i]));
  else
       insert to the hash sum - arr[i]
```

The solution requires extra space for the hash.... What size should be chosen for the hash? Which hash function?

What do you think about that? Is there a better way to solve this?

P.S.
I know an additional solution exists: sort the array; traverse it with two pointers from the end and begining, based if current sum is greater or smaller than `sum`

**Upd.**
It is not the same question for which answers exists  - I am interested in the correct implementation of the hash.

Comment: Yes, you pretty much summarized the two ways of solving the problem. I'm not sure there's much to be said beyond that. (Oh, and it's called 2SUM).

Comment: First, *sort* the array, then find the pairs that make the sum.

Comment: @SChepurin OP knows of this solution. He is interested in implementation of hash.

Comment: The task was "... to return all pairs of the **array's elements**", but you insert `make_pair(arr[i],sum-arr[i])` where `sum-arr[i]` is NOT an element of given array

Comment: @borisbn - it is.read the way how i populate the hush

Comment: @ Abhishek - C++ is also interested in perfect hash implementation. In his case to make it work with repeated elements, also.

Comment: The size of extra space would not exceed n  * sizeof(int) and hash function would be arr[i] % n

Comment: Note, for sort-based solution you can use O(N) sorting, like [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Answer (score 0):

you can use unordered_set which can find a element in O(1)