# How to find all the pairs that sum up to a certain values in any random array using Hashmap in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, hashmap, sum

I want to find all the pairs that in an array that sum upto a certain number X using Hashmap.I know the basic solution which has O(n^2) complexity but somewhere I read that hashmap can provide O(n) solution.I have no idea how can I use hashmap to achieve the solution.Can someone provide me a pseudo code on how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907001/interview-find-all-pairs-of-array-elements-whose-sum-is-known?rq=1

Comment: It takes O(n^2) to just *print out* the solution in a worst case scenario, so unless you don't want it to print the answer you can't get better than O(n^2) for the general case.

Comment: @Dan this is not a homework problem.I am just preparing random questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use something like a `std::set`, then all values in the set would be unique.  This would allow you to loop through the set and do a subtraction from the desired value to determine the other value you would need.  You can then test to see if that value exists in the set.  The operations would look like this:

1. Set iterator to first element in the set
2. Get the value of the first element in the set
3. Subtract the value from the desired value to obtain the needed value
4. Test the set to see if the needed value is in the set
5. If it is record both values
6. Increment the iterator and repeat from #2 until you reach the end of the set

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I'm going to assume you don't really care about including every possible repetition of identical results. If all the items in the input are exactly SUM/2, then you have N<sup>2</sup> results (all identical).

The basic idea is pretty simple: insert all the data into the map. Then for each item `N` in in the hash-map, look for `sum-N`, and if it's present, print out that pair.

From a practical viewpoint, if the size of the input isn't immense, you might be better off with an O(N log N) solution. Start by sorting the input. Then start walking from the beginning and end of the sorted data. You start with the first and last items. If the sum is too large, walk backwards from the end until you get a result less than or equal to the desired sum. If it's equal, print out the pair. Either way, you then increment the beginning pointer and continue searching. Continue until the two pointers meet.

Since this mostly accesses memory linearly, it tends to be very cache friendly. Accessing data in the hash table tends to have much poorer locality of reference, so even though each access has constant (expected) complexity, the constants involved may be high enough that the O(N log N) version may well be faster in practice.